# Need to check for available dates in a for loop and schedule a sale order

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a MS SQL server table having these columns - Date_Allotted, Sale_Order_No, Time_Available.

The contents are like -

```
Date_Allotted  |  Sale_Order_No |  Time_Available   |  Time_Needed  
-------------------------------------------------------------------  
02-02-2015     |    123456      |   90 mins         |   50 mins  
08-02-2015     |    123457      |   70 mins         |   30 mins  
09-02-2015     |    123458      |  120 mins         |  200 mins  
10-02-2015     |    123459      |  320 mins         |  100 mins  
11-02-2015     |    123455      |  40 mins          |   20 mins  
15-02-2015     |    123454      |  30 mins          |   15 mins
```

Time_Available says, how many minutes are available from morning 9 to evening 6:30.

Time_Needed says, number of minutes the sale order needs to get executed.

When a new sale order is added, I want to schedule it when the dates are free, i.e., when on the date there is no sale order scheduled. I need to check the dates in between and check if time is available on that day in a loop.

I am using the following code to get the dates which are not in the series and the dates between them.

I mean, in the above dates, 8th and 9th are in series and dates are available between 2nd and 8th, 9th and 11th and 11th and 15th.

The code is -

To find dates between 2 dates..........

```sql
Declare @Date1 DATETIME, @Date2 DATETIME
set @Date1 = '01/25/2015 12:00:00 AM';
set @Date2 = '02/05/2015 12:00:00 AM';

with daterange as
( select dt = DATEADD(dd, 1, @Date1)
where DATEADD(dd, 1, @Date1) <= @Date2
union all
select DATEADD(dd, 1, dt)
from daterange
where DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) <= @Date2 )
select *
from daterange
```

To find the dates not in series or the dates that have a gap............

```sql
select l.DateAllotted as start
from [DCP].[dbo].[TimeAllotted] as l
left outer join [DCP].[dbo].[TimeAllotted] as r on l.DateAllotted + 1 = r.DateAllotted
where r.DateAllotted is null
```

My function in java is something like this........

```
try
{  
     String tl = "";   

     SimpleDateFormat sdft = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

     st5 = con.createStatement();

     ResultSet rs5 = st5.executeQuery("Select TimeLeft from DCP.dbo.TimeAllotted where DateAllotted = '"+lir.trim()+"'");

     while(rs5.next())
     {
            tl = rs5.getString("TimeLeft");  // it is the time left on that day
            System.out.println("TimeLeft : " + tl);
     }

     rs5.close();  
     st5.close();

     if((("").equals(tl.trim())) || ((" ").equals(tl.trim())))
           tl = "960";

     int ftl = 0, frt = 0;

     tl = tl.trim();

     RoutingTime = RoutingTime.trim(); // it is the time needed to execute a sale order

     ftl = Integer.parseInt(tl);
     System.out.println("ftl: " + ftl);

     frt = Integer.parseInt(RoutingTime);
     System.out.println("frt: " + frt);

     if(ftl >= frt)
     {
          Calendar calb = Calendar.getInstance();
          Calendar calc = Calendar.getInstance();
          Calendar cald = Calendar.getInstance();

          String cdatet = "18:30:00";

          calb.setTime(sdft.parse(cdatet));

          cdatet = sdft.format(calb.getTime());
          System.out.println("Fixed Date Time: " + cdatet);

          String cdateta = "09:00:00";

          cald.setTime(sdft.parse(cdateta));

          cdateta = sdft.format(cald.getTime());
          System.out.println("Fixed Date Time 1: " + cdateta);

          String cdatetc = sdft.format(calc.getTime());

          calc.setTime(sdft.parse(cdatetc));

          cdatetc = sdft.format(calc.getTime());
          System.out.println("Current Date Time: " + cdatetc);

          java.util.Date cdatetd = calb.getTime();
          java.util.Date cdatetcd = calc.getTime();
          java.util.Date cdatetcd1 = cald.getTime();

         int mins = (int) ((calb.getTime().getTime() - calc.getTime().getTime()) / (60000));
         System.out.println("mins : " + mins);

         int TimeLeft = 0;

         if((cdatetcd1.before(cdatetcd)) && (cdatetcd.before(cdatetd)) && (mins >= frt))
                TimeLeft = ftl - frt;

         Statement st3 = con.createStatement();

         String dd = "";

         String sql1 = "SELECT datediff(dd, LastItemReceiptDate, CustomerRequestDate) as 'ddiff' FROM DCP.dbo.DCPDate where SONo = '"+jtfSONo.getText().trim()+"' and LineItemNo = '"+jtfLineItemNo.getText().trim()+"'";

         ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery(sql1);

         while(rs2.next())
          {
                dd = rs2.getString("ddiff");
          }

          rs2.close();  
          st3.close();

          int datediff = 0;

          datediff = Integer.parseInt(dd);
          System.out.println("datediff : " + datediff);

          tl = "" + TimeLeft;

          if(datediff >= 10)
          {
                if(TimeLeft <= frt)
                {
                      Statement st6 = con.createStatement();

                      ArrayList<String> solist = new ArrayList<String>();

                      String sql2i = "select l.DateAllotted as start from [DCP].[dbo].[TimeAllotted] as l left outer join [DCP].[dbo].[TimeAllotted] as r on l.DateAllotted + 1 = r.DateAllotted where r.DateAllotted is null and l.DateAllotted > '"+lir.trim()+"'";  // check which date are not in series

                      ResultSet rs6 = st6.executeQuery(sql2i);

                      while(rs6.next())
                      {
                            solist.add(rs6.getString("Start").trim());
                      }

                      rs6.close();  
                      st6.close();

                      for(int i = 0; i < solist.size(); i++)
                      {
                            for(int j = i; j <= (i+1); j++)
                            {
                                   Statement st7 = con.createStatement();

                                   ArrayList<String> linelist = new ArrayList<String>();  

                                   String sql3 = "Declare @sDate DATETIME, @eDate DATETIME select @sDate = '"+solist.get(i).toString().trim()+"'; select @eDate = '"+solist.get(i+1).toString().trim()+"'; ;with DATE(Date1) as ( select DATEADD(day, datediff(day, '19000101', @sDate), '19000101') union all select DATEADD(day, 1, Date1) from DATE where Date1 <= @eDate ) select convert(varchar(15),d1.DATE1,110) as [Working Date], datename(weekday,d1.Date1)[Working Day] from DATE d1 where (datename(weekday,d1.Date1))not in ('Saturday','Sunday')";  // check free dates using the dates not in series and consider only working dates

                                   ResultSet rs7 = st7.executeQuery(sql3);

                                   while(rs7.next())
                                   {
                                         linelist.add(rs7.getString("Working Date").trim());
                                   }

                                   for(int k = 0; k < linelist.size(); k++)
                                   {
                                         Statement st8 = con.createStatement();

                                        String lefttime = "";

                                        ResultSet rs8 = st8.executeQuery("Select TimeLeft from DCP.dbo.TimeAllotted where DateAllotted = '"+linelist.get(k).toString().trim()+"'"); // take up one date, if time is available, come out of the loop and schedule the sale order on that date.....

                                        while(rs8.next())
                                        {
                                             lefttime = rs8.getString("TimeLeft");
                                             System.out.println("TimeLeft : " + lefttime);
                                        }

                                        if((("").equals(lefttime.trim())) || ((" ").equals(lefttime.trim())))
                                             lefttime = "960";

                                        int ftla = 0, frta = 0;

                                        lefttime = lefttime.trim();

                                        RoutingTime = RoutingTime.trim();

                                        ftla = Integer.parseInt(lefttime);
                                        System.out.println("ftla: " + ftla);

                                        frta = Integer.parseInt(RoutingTime);
                                        System.out.println("frta: " + frta);

                                        if(ftla >= frta)
                                        {
                                             Calendar calbi = Calendar.getInstance();
                                             Calendar calci = Calendar.getInstance();
                                             Calendar caldi = Calendar.getInstance();

                                             String cdateti = "18:30:00";

                                             calbi.setTime(sdft.parse(cdateti));

                                             cdateti = sdft.format(calbi.getTime());
                                             System.out.println("Fixed Date Timei: " + cdateti);

                                             String cdatetai = "09:00:00";

                                             caldi.setTime(sdft.parse(cdatetai));

                                             cdatetai = sdft.format(caldi.getTime());
                                             System.out.println("Fixed Date Time 1i: " + cdatetai);

                                             String cdatetci = sdft.format(calci.getTime());

                                             calci.setTime(sdft.parse(cdatetci));

                                            cdatetci = sdft.format(calci.getTime());
                                            System.out.println("Current Date Timei: " + cdatetci);

                                            java.util.Date cdatetdi = calbi.getTime();
                                            java.util.Date cdatetcdi = calci.getTime();
                                            java.util.Date cdatetcd1i = caldi.getTime();

                                            int minsi = (int) ((calbi.getTime().getTime() - calci.getTime().getTime()) / (60000));
                                            System.out.println("minsi : " + minsi);

                                            int TimeLefti = 0;

                                           if((cdatetcd1i.before(cdatetcdi)) && (cdatetcdi.before(cdatetdi)) && (minsi >= frta))
                                                    TimeLefti = ftla - frta;

                                            lefttime = "" + TimeLefti;

                                            if(TimeLefti >= frta)
                                            {
                                                  EDCDate = linelist.get(k).toString().trim();  
                                                  break;
                                            }
                                      }
                                }
                         }
                  }

                  calca.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

                  // check if the date is free

                  lir = sdf1.format(calca.getTime());
                  System.out.println("lir : " + lir);

                  EDCDate = lir.trim();
             }

             else
             {
                 EDCDate = lir.trim();
             }
       }

       else
       {
          if(TimeLeft <= frt)
          {
                 calda.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

                 cr = sdf1.format(calda.getTime());
                 System.out.println("cr : " + cr);

                 EDCDate = cr.trim();
           }

           else
           {
                   EDCDate = cr.trim();
           }
       }
  }

  else
  {
     Calendar cala = Calendar.getInstance();

     String cdate = sdf.format(cala.getTime());

     cala.setTime(sdf.parse(cdate));

     cdate = sdf1.format(cala.getTime());
     System.out.println("Current Date : " + cdate);

     cala.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

     cdate = sdf1.format(cala.getTime());
     System.out.println("cdate : " + cdate);

     EDCDate = cdate.trim();
     }
     }

     else
     {  
         SimpleDateFormat sdft = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

         st5 = con.createStatement();

         ResultSet rs5 = st5.executeQuery("Select TimeLeft from DCP.dbo.TimeAllotted where DateAllotted = '"+lir.trim()+"'");

         while(rs5.next())
         {
             tl = rs5.getString("TimeLeft");
             System.out.println("TimeLeft : " + tl);
         }

         rs5.close();

         st5.close();

         if((("").equals(tl.trim())) || ((" ").equals(tl.trim())))
              tl = "960";

         int ftl = 0, frt = 0;

         tl = tl.trim();

         RoutingTime = RoutingTime.trim();

         ftl = Integer.parseInt(tl);
         System.out.println("ftl: " + ftl);

        frt = Integer.parseInt(RoutingTime);
        System.out.println("frt: " + frt);

        if(ftl >= frt)
        {
            Calendar calb = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calc = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar cald = Calendar.getInstance();

            String cdatet = "18:30:00";

            calb.setTime(sdft.parse(cdatet));

            cdatet = sdft.format(calb.getTime());
            System.out.println("Fixed Date Time: " + cdatet);

            String cdateta = "09:00:00";

            cald.setTime(sdft.parse(cdateta));

            cdateta = sdft.format(cald.getTime());
            System.out.println("Fixed Date Time 1: " + cdateta);

            String cdatetc = sdft.format(calc.getTime());

            calc.setTime(sdft.parse(cdatetc));

            cdatetc = sdft.format(calc.getTime());
            System.out.println("Current Date Time: " + cdatetc);

            java.util.Date cdatetd = calb.getTime();
            java.util.Date cdatetcd = calc.getTime();
            java.util.Date cdatetcd1 = cald.getTime();

            int mins = (int) ((calb.getTime().getTime() - calc.getTime().getTime()) / (60000));
                                                                        System.out.println("mins : " + mins);

            int TimeLeft = 0;

            if((cdatetcd1.before(cdatetcd)) && (cdatetcd.before(cdatetd)) && (mins >= frt))
                    TimeLeft = ftl - frt;

            if(TimeLeft <= frt)
            {
                 calca.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

                 lir = sdf1.format(calca.getTime());
                 System.out.println("lir : " + lir);

                 EDCDate = lir.trim();
            }

            else
            {
                  EDCDate = lir.trim();
            }
       }

       else
       {
              Calendar cala = Calendar.getInstance();

              String cdate = sdf.format(cala.getTime());

              cala.setTime(sdf.parse(cdate));

              cdate = sdf1.format(cala.getTime());
              System.out.println("Current Date : " + cdate);

              cala.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

              cdate = sdf1.format(cala.getTime());
              System.out.println("cdate : " + cdate);

              EDCDate = cdate.trim();
          }
       }
```

Please guide me.......... **I am not sure about the loops. I need to first check for the dates not in series or the dates that have gap in between. And, then, using those dates, check which all dates are free. Then, check if time is available on that date. If yes, break the loop and schedule the order, else go to next date. Please tell me if the loops are correct or can they be improved on.**

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Java?

Comment: I am confused, if it should be done in java or can be done in sql server itself

Comment: should I add the available dates in between in to a list and loop through the list in java?

Comment: but, my doubt is, if there are more than one dates which are not in series and have gap in between, how will i choose which 2 dates to find the dates in between

Comment: Use the Calendar table (a table with all available dates)

Comment: Hi, calendar table in java? please explain in detail, i did not get..........

Comment: someone please guide me..............

Comment: please help me out with the loops

Answer (score 1):

Create a calendar table in SQL. A table that has every date in it. Then join to it, so you can return all dates, even if they don't appear in your TimeAllotted table.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I have added my code snippet and what I am trying to do. Please guide me.

Comment: I have taken only week days into account, i am able to do it, I am confused about the loops......

Comment: please help me out with the loops

Comment: I wouldn't use loops at all.   I would use a calendar table and join to it for a set-based solution.